# rspec should ensure_length_of allow_nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

Model

```
validates_length_of :description, :maximum => 255, :allow_nil => true
```

spec_file

```
it { should ensure_length_of(:description).is_at_most(255).allow_nil }
```

return exeption

```
Failure/Error: it { should ensure_length_of(:description).is_at_most(255).allow_nil }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `allow_nil' for #<Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::EnsureLengthOfMatcher:0x0000000acb03e0>
```

Pls, help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `allow_nil` method for `Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::EnsureLengthOfMatcher`.

You could use `allow_value`:

```
it { should allow_value(nil).for(:description) }
it { should ensure_length_of(:description).is_at_most(255) }
```

Answer (score 4):

Model

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 255 }, allow_nil: true
end
```

Rspec

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

describe MyModel do
  describe 'validations' do
    it { is_expected.to allow_value(nil).for(:description) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_length_of(:description).is_at_most(255) }
  end
end
```

*P.S. ensure_length_of is deprecated*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `allow_nil` with `validates_length_of` if you're only validating the maximum of characters.

Comment: I can't change model, I need write only tests! It's problem :(